# Weird restart - need help troubleshooting

Tags: high-sierra, restart, library

I restarted my 2011 iMac running High Sierra and after entering my username (this field was blank this time whereas it's usually pre-populated) and password, my desktop came up but I was presented with a dialog box saying something along the lines of `the library must be repaired for your computer to run properly` with a password field. I restarted several times with the same thing each time. finally, I entered my password and the same dialog came right back up (not the wrong-password one where it shakes).

This happened several times but finally stopped and all of my preferences seem to have been wiped. from there I attempted to open Photoshop and got a message saying it couldn't continue due to application errors. I went on to start in recovery mode and ran First Aid on each volume. No luck there either. I started in safe mode and got the same results.

I'm kind of at the end of my rope here. If anyone could lend any insight and/or suggest any additional troubleshooting, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Sounds like a failed Hard Drive. What exactly Happens When Running First aid (what error Code)?

Comment: no error code on any of them

Comment: Yah, could be a disk error that has corrupted/damaged parts of macOS and some apps. Do you have a recent backup? It is possible that if you boot into recovery, reformat the HD and reinstall the OS (and restore your data from backup) the reformatting process **may** map out bad blocks. That would be the cheapest/easiest first step. But depending on the issue may not actually fix the issue, just point out that you do, indeed, have to replace the HD/SSD.

Comment: @SteveChambers - thanks for the intel. definitely have data backup from this morning. kinda sucks - both drives (one HD one SSD) are about 3 years old. Is that normal? At this point, I feel like a decent (i5+, 16bg, flash storage) used mac mini might be a better investment than putting another dime into this dinosaur... and i can keep the 27-incher as 1 of my displays. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you reset your password recently? Maybe, just maybe this is a keychain and account authentication error.

Comment: The issue coming up out of the blue sounds fishy and could be a failed hard drive. Since you have a good backup, you might as well try reinstalling the system software and/or creating a new user account.